# How to show something is not a one-way function?

Tags: one-way-function

Lets say that $f:\{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^*$ is a strong one way function.
Let
$h(x)=f(x)||x_n$ where $x_n$ is the $n$th bit of $x$.

I understand that $h$ will not be a strong one-way function. However, I wish to gain an intuitive understanding why that is.

Comment: The problem is not well defined, because a one way function can have a value with last bit =1 and a second value with last bit=0 in its preimage.

Comment: I improved the language and defined my f.  I hope this makes more sense now

Comment: Can you define "strong one-way function" for us?

Comment: What's $n$? $\ \ \ $

Comment: (By the way, regardless of how $n$ is detemined, the function is very probably one-way, and the proof that it is is trivial.)

Comment: Actually, a previous version of the question stated that $x_n$ is the last bit of $x$, which is much better (although it would be even better to avoid using this extra $n$ altogether, or to define it). I will write an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the proof that $h$ is one-way is not that trivial... First, a reminder on definitions. A function $f$ is (strongly) one-way if for all probabilistic polynomial-time adversaries $A$, all polynomials $p$ and all sufficiently large $n$, we have
$$\mathrm{Pr}[A(f(U_n),1^n) \in f^{-1}(U_n)] < \frac{1}{p(n)}$$
(where $U_n$ represents a random variable with uniform distribution over all strings of length $n$). Put in words, we choose uniformly a string $x$ of length $n$, we compute $y = f(x)$ and we run $A$ on input $(y,1^n)$, noting its output $x'$. Then the definition states that the probability that $f(x') = y$ is less than $1/p(n)$. We prove that $h$ is one-way by contradiction. That is, assuming that $h$ is not one-way, we show that $f$ is not one-way, contradicting our hypothesis.

So what does it mean to say that $h$ is not one-way. It is easily seen that "all sufficiently large" is equivalent to "all but a finite number", so we obtain the following. There is a probabilistic polynomial-time algorithm $A_h$ and a polynomial $p_h$ such that for infinitely many $n$ we have
$$\mathrm{Pr}[A_h(h(U_n),1^n) \in h^{-1}(U_n)] \ge \frac{1}{p_h(n)}.$$
We restrict out attention to such $n$. We will show that there is a probabilistic polynomial-time algorithm $A_f$ and a polynomial $p_f$ such that for all such (infinitely many) $n$, we have
$$\mathrm{Pr}[A_f(f(U_n),1^n) \in f^{-1}(U_n)] \ge \frac{1}{p_f(n)}.$$

$A_f$ works as follows, on input $(f(U_n), 1^n)$ (that is, on input $(y,1^n)$ where $y = f(x)$ for a uniformly chosen $x$ of length $n$).

1. Run $s \gets A_h(y||0,1^n)$. If $f(s) = y$, output $s$ and halt.
2. Run $t \gets A_h(y||1,1^n)$. If $f(t) = y$, output $t$ and halt.
3. Output $0^n$ and halt.

$A_f$ clearly runs in probabilistic polynomial-time, and we analyse its success probability. We observe that if the last bit of $U_n$ is $0$ and the call to $A_h$ in step 1 succeeds, then $A_f$ will succeed. Likewise, if the last bit of $U_n$ is $1$ and the call to $A_h$ in step 2 suceeds, $A_f$ succeeds. Hence (letting $\mathrm{last}(X)$ be the last bit of $X$)
$$\mathrm{Pr}[A_f(f(U_n),1^n) \in f^{-1}(U_n) \mid \mathrm{last}(U_n) = 0] \ge \mathrm{Pr}[A_h(h(U_n),1^n) \in h^{-1}(U_n) \mid \mathrm{last}(U_n) = 0] $$
and
$$\mathrm{Pr}[A_f(f(U_n),1^n) \in f^{-1}(U_n) \mid \mathrm{last}(U_n) = 1] \ge \mathrm{Pr}[A_h(h(U_n),1^n) \in h^{-1}(U_n) \mid \mathrm{last}(U_n) = 1].$$

Now,
$$\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Pr}[A_f(f(U_n),1^n) \in f^{-1}(U_n)]
  &= \mathrm{Pr}[A_f(f(U_n),1^n) \in f^{-1}(U_n) \wedge \mathrm{last}(U_n) = 0] \\
  &\quad {}+{} \mathrm{Pr}[A_f(f(U_n),1^n) \in f^{-1}(U_n) \wedge \mathrm{last}(U_n) = 1] \\
  &= \mathrm{Pr}[A_f(f(U_n),1^n) \in f^{-1}(U_n) \mid \mathrm{last}(U_n) = 0]\cdot \mathrm{Pr}[\mathrm{last}(U_n) = 0] \\
  &\quad {}+{} \mathrm{Pr}[A_f(f(U_n),1^n) \in f^{-1}(U_n) \mid \mathrm{last}(U_n) = 1]\cdot \mathrm{Pr}[\mathrm{last}(U_n) = 1] \\
  &\ge \mathrm{Pr}[A_h(h(U_n),1^n) \in h^{-1}(U_n) \mid \mathrm{last}(U_n) = 0]\cdot \mathrm{Pr}[\mathrm{last}(U_n) = 0] \\
  &\quad {}+{} \mathrm{Pr}[A_h(h(U_n),1^n) \in h^{-1}(U_n) \mid \mathrm{last}(U_n) = 1]\cdot \mathrm{Pr}[\mathrm{last}(U_n) = 1] \\
  &\ge \mathrm{Pr}[A_h(h(U_n),1^n) \in h^{-1}(U_n) \wedge \mathrm{last}(U_n) = 0] \\
  &\quad {}+{} \mathrm{Pr}[A_h(h(U_n),1^n) \in h^{-1}(U_n) \wedge \mathrm{last}(U_n) = 1] \\
  &\ge \mathrm{Pr}[A_h(h(U_n),1^n) \in h^{-1}(U_n)] \\
  &\ge \frac{1}{p_h(n)}.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: $p(n) = C$ is a polynomial.

Comment: Your proof is an explicit version of my scetch below. Its good to have a complete formal proof, but a scetch is probably better for gaining an intuitive understanding.

Comment: @HenrickHellström I suppose you are saying we could just make a random guess for the last bit instead of trying both? Feel free to write it as an answer.

Comment: @fkraiem: I am saying that the condition "all polynomials $p$" in the definition of strong one-way function your answer, probably isn't what you meant. For all candidate functions, it is possible to choose a constant polynomial that makes the inequality false. Hence, no strong one-way functions exists.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, $h(x)$ is one-way. Probably what puzzles your intuition is, that the definition of one-way functions is an asymptotic statement over a whole family of functions indexed by $n$.

Proof (scetch):
Assume $h(x)$ is not one-way. 
This means, there exists an algorithm $A$, which for uniformly chosen $x$ calculates  a preimage $x_0$ to $h(x) = y \| x_n$ with non-negligible probability.
Since $f(x_0) = y$, the algorithm $A$ also computes a preimage for $f(x)$ with non-neglible probability. This contradicts the assumption that $f$ is one-way.  This in turn says that the non one-way assumption on $h$ is wrong.
qed.

Comment: -1 for "arbitrarily chosen $y$ and $x_n$", that's not how it works. The algorithm operates on $f(x)||x_n$ for a uniformly (not arbitrarily) chosen $x$. (And we still don't know what $n$ is.)

Comment: @fkraiem: The proof is a scetch only and as such its IMHO correct. Since this is presumably a learner's question I think its more educative to let the gaps fill out by himself. If some important point is missing, you can comment this. I will then try to improve my answer. But downgrading the answer is in my opinion a bit unfair.

Comment: Speaking of "arbitrarily chosen $y$ and $x_n$" is not "sketchy", it is wrong.

Comment: @fkraiem: replaced arbitrary with uniform. Please check.

Comment: No, you're still not getting it. $y$ is *not* uniformly chosen, it is the result of applying $f$ to a uniformly chosen $x$. It is not the same thing, unless we assume that $f$ is a one-way *permutation*, which is not the case here.